# Opt out of Facebook comment updates

Tags: facebook

Is there a way (at the Facebook end, not via filtering my end) to opt-out of receiving notifications every time someone else adds a comment to a thread I am involved in?

Comment: Have you tried removing your comments ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the `"Account"` drop down menu (upper right hand corner of the page) then click `"Account Settings"` and go to the `"Notifications"` tab. Go through the list of notifications and deselect any notification you don't want. Fifteen out of the sixty-six notifications represented on this page are triggered by comments.

To opt-out of notifications for treads you're involved in, deselect the six notifications that start with: "Comments after me..."

Comment: *Exactly* what I was after, thanks.