# Mute Facebook comment threads after clicking Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications, mute

When I Like or comment on a Facebook entry, I get notified on every single comment for the rest of the thread. Sometimes I want that, and sometimes I don't.

I know I can [opt out of these notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/opt-out-of-facebook-comment-updates) entirely, but I just want to mute a few noisy Facebook threads, NOT all of them.

Is this possible?

Comment: One thing I'll note: Gmail's "Mute" feature doesn't seem to do the right thing. It groups all emails with the subject "X commented on Y's status" into one big thread and mutes the whole thing. That's not what I want!

Comment: you can edit your question and include that part.. because that's one way.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For pictures, pages and profiles to my knowledge no.

For new groups you can unsubscribe from a thread you liked in the group.

Rollover the post and click unsubscribe/subscribe as below
`0 minutes ago · Comment · Like · Subscribe`

Answer (score 1):

You can click on that notification which will open the post. You will see the option 'unfollow post' just next to like. Click that and you will be excluded from updates about that post.